# What movie could Trimmau have watched?

Tags: fate-zero

in [Trimmau's Wikia Page](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Trimmau) it says she's developed a fault where

> she rampages around occasionally thinking that she is a "killer robot from the future" due to the movie she watched in development.

I am wondering if this is a real movie or a reference to Type-Moon's [2012 April Fool's joke](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/April_Fools'_Day#Koha-Ace_.282012.29)?

<sup>i have chosen Fate/Zero as the tag because Trimmau was originally Kayneth's  Volumen Hydrargyrum Mystic Code until Waver reprogrammed it after the forth war</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since her features resembles a certain [liquid metal Terminator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-1000), it's very likely this is a reference to [*Terminator 2*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_2:_Judgment_Day).

From [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103064/):

> A cyborg, identical to the one who failed to kill Sarah Connor, must now protect her young son, John Connor, from a more advanced cyborg, made out of liquid metal.